# Executing an overwritten inherited function

Tags: c++, inheritance

Say I have these two classes:

```
class Object {
public:
    virtual void update();      
};

class Actor : public Object {
public:
    void update();
}
```

Also assume that I am creating instances of the `actor` class as follows:

```
class somethingElse {
public:
    void init();

    std::vector<Object*> objects;
}

void somethingElse::init()
{
    Actor tmp;
    Object * tmpo = &tmp;
    objects.push_back(tmpo);
}
```

I later iterate through `objects`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
    objects.at(i)->update();
```

Placing a breakpoint at the two versions of `update()` revealed that the one being called is the one from the `object` class, and not the one from the `actor` class. Why is this, and is there any way around this problem?

Comment: With the code you show, is the `Actor` object `tmp` still in scope and alive when you call the `update` function? If possible, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No it is not.

Comment: Then that's the problem. You have a pointer to a non-existing object. Dereferencing it will lead to *undefined behavior*. Consider using dynamic allocation (preferably using smart pointers) instead.

Comment: Cannot reproduce [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7a5b5342921f422)

Comment: Also, `Object` should have a virtual destructor.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Would creating the `Actor` object using the `new` operator solve the issue?

Comment: @qwarten -- Using `new` will temporarily solve your problem.  Then you get into the issue of possible memory leaks if you don't deallocate the memory, and the undefined behavior if you did attempt to deallocate (since you're missing the virtual destructor, as mentioned before).

Comment: Yes. But please consider something like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) first. The smart pointers of modern C++ will help you and make life so much easier as a C++ programmer.

Comment: Alright, thanks to both of you, will look up smart pointers. Is the existence of a virtual destructor enough to solve the problem you mention, @PaulMcKenzie ?

Comment: @qwarten -- Since you have a `vector<Object*>`, if you used `new Actor` and placed that in the vector, at some point you have to `delete` that vector item.  Without a virtual destructor, deleting an object through a base class pointer is undefined behavior.  So yes, you must have a virtual destructor for `Object` for this not to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `somethingElse::init()` `Actor tmp` will go out of scope and be destroyed. The pointer will point to an object that no longer exists.

`new` could help here, but it would be safer to use a smart pointer, such as `std::shared_ptr` for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Object {
public:
    virtual void update() { std::cout << "Object update()\n"; }
    virtual ~Object() = default;
};

class Actor : public Object {
public:
    void update()  { std::cout << "Actor update()\n"; }
};

class somethingElse {
public:
    void init();

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> objects;
};

void somethingElse::init()
{
    //Actor tmp;
    auto tmpo = std::make_shared<Actor>();
    //Object * tmpo = &tmp;
    objects.push_back(tmpo);
}

int main()
{
    somethingElse objs;
    objs.init();
    auto& objects = objs.objects;


    for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
        objects.at(i)->update();
}
```